# auto complete first letter only in text box by javascript

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I am in stage to do auto complete by first letter only in text box if any source are available kindly post the link to see........`i have searched in google only showing it in Jquery....but i need in javascript....`

Comment: Please post your code.. as far as you have tried..

Comment: sry still now i did't tried am searching for any tutorial or some example

Answer (score 1):

The core of an autocomplete script will be the ajax call to the dictionary of terms.

I assume that your application already includes an ajax function, Basically all you need in an input tag, a keyup event handler that triggers the ajax call, and a div to collect the response.

Some references from a blog:

http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/gr/column5/index.html

http://ejohn.org/blog/revised-javascript-dictionary-search/

http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-livesearch/

Comment: first link cant be loaded

Comment: loads completely for me. @jagan4040

Answer (score 1):

Here are some useful website for auto-suggest text box in JavaScript

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?119753-Simple-auto-complete-function

http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/autocomplete-form.php

**Updated Link :**

http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/ncz/index.html

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/auto-completion-scripts/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20174/Auto-suggest-Control

Comment: second link is useful while searching it words cant be shown fully its end up continue in second line if word are too large how to overcome this...

Comment: i have updated some links below you can try that.. if that suites you, you can give the answer correct and vote up.@jagan4040

Comment: Thanks.. then the Solution has been got and just close the answer but ticking it..

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript onKeyUp Event.

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)">
```